# Como utilizar checkbox com ngFor?

Tags: angular, typescript

Eu estou iniciando em Angular no meu colégio e preciso fazer um projeto de um site médico. Em uma das partes tenho o seguinte template:

```html
<div class="container mt-5 mb-5">
    <h3>Qual a doença?</h3>
    <div class="container" *ngFor="let doenca of doencas;let i= index">
        <div class='col-2'> 
              <div class="form-check">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" [(ngModel)]="paciente.doenca" name="{{doenca}}" >
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">{{doenca}}</label>
                </div>
        </div>
       <p *ngIf="paciente.doenca==true && doenca=='febre'">
          <input type="radio" name="alta">Febre alta
          <input type="radio" name="media">Febre media
          <input type="radio" name="baixa">Febre alta
       </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

e o seguinte código:

```js
paciente:Paciente; 
 doencas=["febre","desmaio","vomito"];
```

(dentro do model paciente existem diversos atributos,entre eles estão os três que estão citados no array doencas)

Quero que ao clicar no checkbox mudasse o valor do atributo da doença correspondente em paciente e após isso aparecesse a tag "p" com o resto das perguntas relacionada a doença. Mas do jeito que tá,quando eu clico toda as checkbox são marcadas. Como resolver?

Comment: Não ficou clara sua pergunta, poderia postar como é a classe **Paciente**?

Comment: Aqui está o link do GitHub pra facilitar(o código que tá dando problema está em edit-pediatra) :https://github.com/JuanGustah/PPO

Answer (score 1):

Juan, ao clicar no checkbox altere o valor de uma variável e faça com que seu `<p>` utilize esta variável para ser ou não exibido:

```
<input type="checkbox" (change)="minhaVariavel = $event.target.checked" />
<p *ngIf="minhaVariavel">...</p>
```

Outro ponto é que os radios devem ter em seu `name` uma identificação que torna aquele grupo único. Ao utilizar um `name` diferente nos 3 radios possibilitará que o usuário selecione mais de um. Para ajustar:

```
<input type="radio" name="algumaIdentificacao1" value="alta">Febre alta
<input type="radio" name="algumaIdentificacao1" value="media">Febre media
<input type="radio" name="algumaIdentificacao1" value="baixa">Febre alta
```

Abaixo há um exemplo funcional baseado no seu cenário mas provavelmente diferente, já que não há todas as informações na pergunta.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  doencas = [
    { nome: 'Doença 1', checked: false, nivel: null },
    { nome: 'Doença 2', checked: false, nivel: null },
    { nome: 'Doença 3', checked: true, nivel: 'alta' }
  ];
}
```

Template:

```
<div *ngFor="let doenca of doencas">
  <input type="checkbox" 
    class="form-check-input" 
    name="{{doenca}}"
    (change)="doenca.checked = !doenca.checked"
    [checked]="doenca.checked" >
  <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">{{doenca.nome}}</label>
  <br />
  <input
    type="radio" 
    [disabled]="!doenca.checked"
    [name]="doenca.nome"
    [checked]="doenca.nivel == 'alta'"
    (change)="doenca.nivel = 'alta'"
    value="alta">Febre alta

  <input
    type="radio"
    [disabled]="!doenca.checked"
    [name]="doenca.nome"
    [checked]="doenca.nivel == 'alta'"
    (change)="doenca.nivel = 'media'"
    value="media">Febre media

  <input 
    type="radio" 
    [disabled]="!doenca.checked"
    [name]="doenca.nome"
    [checked]="doenca.nivel == 'alta'"
    (change)="doenca.nivel = 'baixa'"
    value="baixa">Febre baixa
  <br />
  <br />
</div>
```

Exemplo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f1h8n5